# AJAX request png/jpeg image from (NodeJS + Express) server and show it in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, server

basically I need to receive png or jpeg image from my server, and show it inside img tag on my website.

My architecture looks like this:

Client - Server1 (my server) - Server2 (some public server)

1. Client sends Ajax request to Server1.
2. Server1 sends request to Server2.
3. Server2 sends image back to Server1.
4. Server1 sends image back to Client.

Client code:

```js
$("#testButton").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "get",
    async: false,
    url: "/test"
  }).done(function (response){
    alert(response.imageData);
    $("#resultImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + response.imageData);
  });
});
```

Server1 code:

```js
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
  var url = 'https://ion.gemma.feri.um.si/ion/services/geoserver/demo1/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=demo1%3Amaribor-dof25&bbox=546631.6237364038%2C156484.86830455417%2C550631.7865026393%2C160485.0310707898&width=767&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3794&format=image%2Fjpeg';
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
    console.log(body);
    return res.json({ imageData: body});
  });
});
```

If I enter the url above directly to img src, it is shown correctly.
Image is also shown correctly when I input url directly into browser.

When I receive image data back to my client from server1, data looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Hello. Yes, your answer helped to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're building a `base64` encoded image on the front end, the backend must return a `base64` encoded image.

You are returning the image in `utf8` format which of course won't work. `utf8` is the default encoding when using `request` package.

You can use `encoding` property of the `request` package for that. Or pass `encoding: null` & convert `body` to a `base64` string using `.toString('base64')`

```
request({ url, encoding: 'base64' }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
    console.log(body);
    return res.json({ imageData: body});
});
```

Now `response.imageData` is a `base64` encoded string that you can use with:  `data:image/png;base64,`

Have in mind that you're harcoding `png` on the front end. If you're going to work with different extensions, you can send the full `src` from the server:

```
// 'content-type' must not be image/png or image/jpeg, improve the logic
// I'll leave that to you.
const src = `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64,${body}`;

return res.json({ src });
```

Another option, is to remove the ajax, and send the image directly, without `base64`.

**front**

```
$("#resultImage").attr("src", "/test");
```

**back**

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
   let url = 'https://ion.gemma.feri.um.si/ion/services/geoserver/demo1/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=demo1%3Amaribor-dof25&bbox=546631.6237364038%2C156484.86830455417%2C550631.7865026393%2C160485.0310707898&width=767&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3794&format=image%2Fjpeg';

   request(url).pipe(res);
});
```